# set jquery cookie with attr(href)

Tags: jquery, cookies

I have a script from this demo: [tutorialzine.com](http://demo.tutorialzine.com/2010/03/microtut-getting-and-setting-cookies-with-jquery-php/demo.php)

As you can see the cookie is saved as plain text. However I need it to be saved as a link. So I tried:

```
// If the cookie has been set in a previous page load, show it in the div directly:
if(cookie) $('.jq-text').text(cookie).show();

    $('.fields a').click(function(e){

        var text = $('#inputBox').val();

// Setting a cookie with a seven day validity:

        $.cookie('demoCookie',text,{expires: 7, path: '/', domain: 'domain.com'});

            $('.jq-text').attr('href', text).html(text);
```

I don't know what exactly to change in order to 'attr' the 'var text' and save it as $cookie.

please take a look at the demo: [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mrxu5/3/)

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems to be because of the variable "cookie". Renaming it to "demoCookie" seems to fix the problem...

Comment: How did you figure that out... That is not the case.

Comment: @Youss See http://jsfiddle.net/mrxu5/7/
There might have been something else that I changed, but it worked as soon as I changed the variable name.

Comment: Im going to test your fiddle at home (about 10 hours from now) But on jsfiddle it doesn't work..You are aware that the saved link has to still be there on page refrech ...(hence the cookie...) I also see now reference to the cookie plugin...(So I don't think its gong to work, I appreciate the effort though)

Comment: Sorry about that! It's rather hard to test code changes across reloads with jsfiddle though, without creating 100 saves... I went and found [a different cookie plugin](https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie) over [here](http://jsfiddle.net/mrxu5/15/) which doesn't work in JSFiddle, but works fine locally... Weird.